# Como verificar na API se um usuário que está sendo buscado no banco é o usuário que está logado?

Tags: laravel, api, mvc, auth, model

Estou usando Laravel e eu preciso criar um atributo (is_me) no model para saber se o perfil atual pertence ao usuário que está logado;

Eu estava fazendo como abaixo, mas agora que estou usando API não posso mais usar Auth::user()

```
public function getIsMeAttribute(){
    return \Auth::user()->id == $this->id;
}
```

Comment: Como você autentica seu usuário? JWT? Oauth? Como está a segurança de sua API?

Comment: Estou usando o método de token - não sei ao certo se isso se encaixa em Oauth

Comment: Então provavelmente este token está relacionado ao usuário que está autenticado, correto? Se não seria interessante que o fizesse, ao gerar o token relacionar ao usuário, desta forma antes de realizar o teste que você colocou em código, pesquise o usuário autenticado pelo token e então teste se os ids são iguais